# How to clear old UICollectionViewCell Data to avoid repeating cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

my collectionview cells are repeating multiple times. I posted a question on this before too... [Check the Question with source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537544/uicollectionviewcell-one-of-the-section-from-uicollectionview-cell-repeating-sam)

**Before it was repeating 10 times now reduced to 5 times per same cell.. because I used**

```
image.image = nil
```

But I wanted to completely stop the repeating cell.

I tried Custom Cells, Reset / clear data source before reload data and tried almost every possible solution from google search results.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What method are you using to display the image in the cell?

Comment: What's the difference between this and your previous question? Please [edit] to explain. Reposting is not acceptable here.

Comment: can you give a solution ? I didn't found any complete solution that's why?

Answer (score 1):

You should override `- (void)prepareForReuse;` and clean up the cell contents from there.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    image.image = nil;
}
```